# how to deploy with pivotal tc server of STS

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

[I have a backend project using STS and TC Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eoCy.png)

> i can't deploy my project to the server i get **404 not found.**

Comment: You need to provide more details of what is going wrong

Comment: i have no errors,but when i run with pivotal tc server i got 404 not found